# Skyrim - How to remain neutral on Thirsk Mead Hall quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Talking to either of these guys starts the corresponding quest lines which can, as it seems, only be removed from quest list by either slaughtering all reiklings, or all Nords. I really don't want to do either - let them kill each other. So how can I remove these quests from my list without having to kill anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are playing on a PC, you can remove them with one of the [following console commands](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29):

Chief of Thirsk Hall:

```
SetObjectiveCompleted DLC2MH02  1 1  
CompleteQuest DLC2MH02
```

Retaking Thirsk:

```
SetObjectiveCompleted DLC2MH01  1 1  
CompleteQuest DLC2MH01
```

Being:

1. Used to set the quest stage as being completed or uncompleted;
2. Complete a quest. May cause buggy behavior, SetStage is generally cleaner;
3. DLC2MH02 the quest ID for [The Chief of Thirsk Hall](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Chief_of_Thirsk_Hall)
4. DLC2MH01 the quest ID for [Retaking Thirsk](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Retaking_Thirsk)

Comment: You would be receiving upvotes instead of downvotes if you provided the actual commands rather than the syntax.

Comment: @kotekzot Done :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you want to resolve this in-game.
Based on the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thirsk_Mead_Hall) there isn't any way to peacefully resolve the quest.

If you just want to leave the quest unresolved and simply not have it show up in your quest log (and you're on the PC), you can use console commands to set the quest to completed. Note that you will end up alienating one side or the other anyways, and as such this is *not* a good solution if you are trying to remain neutral.

Comment: Why the unexplained downvote? Is my answer incorrect?

Comment: wasn't me who downvoted..